# Define an object with fixed keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given a situation where you have a data structure that is a map of different configuration values:

```
interface TabConfig {
  label: string
  slug: string
  color: string
}

const tabs = {
  home: {
    label: 'Home',
    slug: 'site-home',
    color: 'blue'
  } satisfies TabConfig,
  about: {
    label: 'About',
    slug: 'about-us',
    color: 'blue'
  } satisfies TabConfig,
  contact: {
    label: 'Contact Us',
    slug: 'contact',
    color: 'green'
  } satisfies TabConfig,
}
type TabName = keyof typeof tabs
```

This has the effect that `TabName` is the literal `'home' | 'about' | 'contact'` instead of `string` (which is good for further type checking to ensure it is truly the name of one of the saved configurations).

The thing I'm not thrilled about this setup is the requirement to remember to put the `satisfies TabConfig` on every entry. Having that annotation helps make sure none of the properties are misspelled or forgotten. But it adds a lot of repeating `satisfies` boilerplate.

Changing the `tabs` type to be `const tabs: { [tabName: string]: TabConfig } = {...` allows dropping the `satisfies` declarations, but then `TabName` becomes `string | number` (too generic).

Changing the `tabs` type to be `const tabs: Record<string, TabConfig> = {...` also allows dropping the `satisfies` declarations, but then `TabName` becomes `string` (too generic).

A few examples I've seen manually declare `type TabName = 'home' | 'about' | 'contact'`, but to me that method seems cumbersome for adding new items to the set, since you have to remember to add the new name in two places (once in `TabName` type definition, and then again in `tabs`).

So, is there a more concise way to declare this configuration mapping to have values that are a specific type, and also end up with a type that is just the compile-time keys present in that mapping, more concisely than using `satisfies` on every declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `satisfies` on the top level, not for each property:

```
const tabs = {
  home: {
    label: 'Home',
    slug: 'site-home',
    color: 'blue'
  } ,
  about: {
    label: 'About',
    slug: 'about-us',
    color: 'blue'
  } ,
  contact: {
    label: 'Contact Us',
    slug: 'contact',
    color: 'green'
  } ,
} satisfies Record<string, TabConfig>
```

```
// type TabName = "home" | "about" | "contact
type TabName = keyof typeof tabs
```